# R : Finding the corresponding row value

Tags: r

I'm trying to get the data from column one that matches with column 2 but only on the "B" values. Need to somehow make the true values a list. 
Need this to repeat for 50,000 rows. Around 37,000 of them are true. 
I'm incredibly new to this so any help would be nice.

```
Data <- data.frame(
X = sample(1:10),
Y = sample(c("B", "W"), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
Count <- 1
If(data[count,2] == "B") {
  List <- list(data[count,1]
  Count <- count + 1
#I'm not sure what to use to repeat I just put
Repeat
} else {
Count <- count + 1
Repeat
}
```

End result should be a list() of only column one data. 
In this if rows 1-5 had "B" I want the column one numbers from that.

Comment: Could you add a minimal example of what you try to do, including the expected outcome?!

Comment: Please edit your question, giving a simple example and the expected outcome. In the meantime, it is really hard to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: We need to have your data (at least its structure) and have a reproducible code to run and see where you're stuck. Please check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2864184) for a guideline.

Comment: What would the result look like?

Comment: Should be a list with the values from column one. Only the ones that match "B" in column 2. Don't know how that would look in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you're looking for, but from the comments I would assume that this might help:

```
setNames(data.frame(Data[1][Data[2]=="B"]), "selected")
#  selected
#1        2
#2        5
#3        7
#4        6
```

No loop needed.

---

**data**

```
Data <- structure(list(X = c(10L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 6L), 
              Y = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), 
             .Label = c("B", "W"), class = "factor")), 
             .Names = c("X", "Y"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), 
              class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is the second part "data" for?

Comment: Just to show which data I used for this example. It connects the result to the input, thereby making the output reproducible.

Comment: Thanks again needed that.